# How do I export a package to Jackson Databind?

Tags: java, jackson-databind

For a class project I have been working on, I am required to read data from a json file and import it into an inventory that I have created. The program had no issues until I reached this step, and I have found that no matter how much I look for a solution, there is not one that solves the error that I am seeing now. The error is an InaccessibleObjectException, and it details that it is unable to make my public class called Weapon accessible.

This is my console output.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public Store.Weapon() accessible: module Milestone1 does not "exports Store" to module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.checkAndFixAccess(ClassUtil.java:939)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.CreatorCollector._fixAccess(CreatorCollector.java:263)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.CreatorCollector.setDefaultCreator(CreatorCollector.java:123)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._addDeserializerConstructors(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:383)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:283)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:224)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:220)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:414)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:479)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4405)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.10.3/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3079)
    at Milestone1/Store.inventoryManager.readFromFile(inventoryManager.java:33)
    at Milestone1/Store.inventoryManager.<init>(inventoryManager.java:58)
    at Milestone1/Store.storeFront.<init>(storeFront.java:18)
    at Milestone1/Shopping.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

**inventoryManager**

```
package Store;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 * 
 * @author Breanna Gernon
 *
 */
public class inventoryManager {
    private ArrayList<ShopItem> inventory;
    private int inventoryCount;
    
    
    private static ArrayList<ShopItem> readFromFile(String filename){
        ArrayList<ShopItem> items = new ArrayList<ShopItem>();
        try
        {
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
            
            while(s.hasNext()) {
                String json = s.nextLine();
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                ShopItem item = new ShopItem();
                if(json.contains("damage")) {
                    
                    item = objectMapper.readValue(json, Weapon.class);
                }
                
                else if (json.contains("healing")){
                    item = objectMapper.readValue(json, Health.class);
                }
                
                else if (json.contains("strength")) {
                    item = objectMapper.readValue(json, Armor.class);
                }
                
                items.add(item);
            }
            
            s.close();
        }
        
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return items;
    }
    
    public inventoryManager() {
        inventory = readFromFile("inventory.json");
        this.inventoryCount = calcCount();
    }
    
    /**
     * Calculate inventory count.
     * @return the inventory count
     */
    public int calcCount() {
        int inCount = 0;
        
        for (ShopItem item : inventory) {
            inCount += item.getQuantity();
        }
        return inCount;
    }
    
    /**
     * Getter
     * @return inventory count
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return inventoryCount;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @return the number of different items in the store.
     */
    public int getSize() {
        return inventory.size();
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @return a list of the names of shop items.
     */
    public String printItemNames() {
        String itemList = "";
        for(ShopItem i : inventory) {
            itemList +=(i.getName());
            itemList += ("    ");
        }
        
        return itemList;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param item - ShopItem object
     * Restocks one item, adding 1 to the item's quantity.
     * Used for returns.
     */
    public void restock(ShopItem item) {
        ShopItem restockItem = inventory.get(inventory.indexOf(item));
        if (inventory.size() > 0) {
            inventory.get(inventory.indexOf(restockItem)).setQuantity(restockItem.getQuantity()+ 1);
        }
        updateCount();
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Updates the inventory count when needed.
     */
    public void updateCount() {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++) {
            this.inventoryCount += inventory.get(i).getQuantity();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param item- ShopItem object
     * When sold out, removes item from stock.
     */
    public void removeItem(ShopItem item) {
        inventory.remove(item);
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param newItem- ShopItem object
     * 
     * When a new item arrives, adds item to inventory.
     */
    public void addItem(ShopItem newItem) {
        if (inventory.size() < 7) {
            inventory.add(newItem);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param soldItem- ShopItem object
     * Updates inventory when an item is sold.
     */
    public void sellItem(ShopItem soldItem) {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++) {
            inventory.get(inventory.indexOf(soldItem)).setQuantity(soldItem.getQuantity() - 1);
        }
        
        updateCount();
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param name- Represents an item's name
     * @return true if the item exists in the inventory, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isItem(String name) {
        for (ShopItem item : this.inventory ) {
            if  (item.getName().equals(name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param name - Represents an item's name
     * @return the location of an item in the arraylist.
     */
    public int findIndex(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++) {
            if (inventory.get(i).getName().equals(name)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param name- Represents an item's name
     * @return an item from the inventory
     */
    public ShopItem getItem(String name) {
        if (isItem(name)) {
            return this.inventory.get(findIndex(name));
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    /**
     * Update one inventory item quantity.
     * @param returnedItem
     */
    public void returnOne(ShopItem returnedItem) {
        ShopItem restockItem = inventory.get(inventory.indexOf(returnedItem));
        restockItem.setQuantity(restockItem.getQuantity() + 1);
        updateCount();
    }
    
    /**
     * Increase each item in the inventory by one.
     * @param returnedCart
     */
    public void returnAll(ArrayList<ShopItem> returnedCart) {
        for (ShopItem item : returnedCart) {
            returnOne(item);
        }
        updateCount();
    }
    
    
}
```

module-info.java

```
module Milestone1 {
    
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;

}
```

I am using Java 11 and have the jackson-annotations-2.10.5.jar, the jackson-core-2.10.5.jar, and the jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar installed per specifications of my assignment.
[My Package Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJnuT.png)

I was trying to set it up so depending on what kind of object it is, it will create an object of that type and add it to an ArrayList of items. This is so I can initialize the inventory with an outside json file, rather than hardwiring it into the program. I am not sure what to try to fix it, since I have never seen this error before. If I need to add in any other details to clarify my code or my assignment, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that adding exports on module-info solved this issue.

```
module Milestone1 {
    exports Milestone1;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
}
```

I thinks exports keyword makes package accesible from other packages.